# Java framework for social network

Tags: java, python, django, seam, pinax

Is there a Java analogue to Pinax/Django? (Perhaps an extension to Jboss Seam and/or functionality already built into Seam?)

Please analyse and compare Pinax/Django, Seam, and any other good Java/Python frameworks in the following criteria (ranked in order of importance):

- Security (sensitive financial information)
- Ability to interact with GWT/JSON-RPC (and possibly Pyjamas, though I'm leaning toward GWT due to the availability of visual design applications)
- Scalability
- Built-in functionality / social network backend logic (e.g. user management, "tweets", etc.)
- Simplicity in setting up and working with
- Synergy with Apache, PostgreSQL, GWT, and mobile applications (iPhone and Android)

If possible, a direct recommendation would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://eurekastreams.org seems to have most of what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to try Apache Shinding

http://incubator.apache.org/projects/shindig.html

And if you want a youtube demostration try

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcWszaReqXI

taken from this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283922/what-are-the-best-java-social-networking-frameworks)

Comment: I didn't know about this before. Thanks. Its a container, though. +1

Comment: Thanks. More specifically, on Mark's recommendation, I'll be using Eureka Streams (partially based on Shindig).